# how to convert Matlab scripts in R

Tags: r, matlab, octave

I would like to run some Matlab scripts. Nevertheless we don't have the Matlab licence so it is necessary a conversion from Matlab to R language. Unfortunately I'm totally new in Matlab but not in R. Is it possible to read Matlab scripts using R or is there an easy way to translate Matlab scripts in R?

Comment: My first attempt would be to see if the scripts work OK in [octave](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), a free, opensource implementation of Matlab.

Comment: Why not try [Octave](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), it's free and syntactically similar to Matlab in most cases.  In some cases there are differences, but the Octave help will be able to tell you the differences.

Comment: What about Scilab? There is a Matlab to Scilab converter: http://help.scilab.org/docs/5.3.0/en_US/About_M2SCI_tools.html

Comment: Hi guys, thanks a lot for your help! I'll try soon the tools you suggest me!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Rewriting from one language to another can be a painstaking process, especially because your have to take great care that the outcomes of both sets of codes are the same. I see roughly four approaches:

- Digest the goal of the scripts, put aside the matlab code, and rewrite in R
- Try and mimic the matlab code in R
- Run the matlab code in octave, and interface with R
- Run the code in Octave entirely

These are roughly in order of amount of work. If you just want to get the Matlab code working, definitely use Octave, which should run the code with minimal changes. If you want to convert the code to R, and continue developing in R, I would go for the first option. In that way you can leverage the real strenghts of R, as R is quite different ([link with info](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2007-March/127981.html), [comparison R and matlab](http://mathesaurus.sourceforge.net/octave-r.html)). But it does take the largest amount of time. Even if you reimplement in R, I would recommend getting the code running in Octave to be able to see if your results in R fit with the Matlab code.

Comment: @EleonoraLusito rather than installing Octave on your system you may quickly test if it works online at http://hughesbennett.net/Octave . It's not exactly the same but might give you an indication and is much quicker. If your code doesn't run in Octave due to some incompatibility, report it to the Octave project at http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?func=additem&group=octave since these are considered bugs.