# Converting matlab code to R code

Tags: r, matlab

I was wondering how I can convert this code from Matlab to R code. It seems this is the code for midpoint method. Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
% Usage: [y t] = midpoint(f,a,b,ya,n) or y = midpoint(f,a,b,ya,n)
% Midpoint method for initial value problems
%
% Input:
% f - Matlab inline function f(t,y)
% a,b - interval
% ya - initial condition
% n - number of subintervals (panels)
%
% Output:
% y - computed solution
% t - time steps
%
% Examples:
% [y t]=midpoint(@myfunc,0,1,1,10);          here 'myfunc' is a user-defined function in M-file
% y=midpoint(inline('sin(y*t)','t','y'),0,1,1,10);
% f=inline('sin(y(1))-cos(y(2))','t','y');
% y=midpoint(f,0,1,1,10);

function [y t] = midpoint(f,a,b,ya,n)
h = (b - a) / n;
halfh = h / 2;
y(1,:) = ya;
t(1) = a;
for i = 1 : n
    t(i+1) = t(i) + h;
    z = y(i,:) + halfh * f(t(i),y(i,:));
    y(i+1,:) = y(i,:) + h * f(t(i)+halfh,z);
end;
```

I have the R code for Euler method which is

```
euler <- function(f, h = 1e-7, x0, y0, xfinal) {
                       N = (xfinal - x0) / h
                       x = y = numeric(N + 1)
                       x[1] = x0; y[1] = y0
                       i = 1
                       while (i <= N) {
                       x[i + 1] = x[i] + h
                       y[i + 1] = y[i] + h * f(x[i], y[i])
                       i = i + 1
                                                }
                       return (data.frame(X = x, Y = y))
                                       }
```

so based on the matlab code, do I need to change h in euler method (R code) to (b - a) / n to modify Euler code to midpoint method?

Comment: @Sardar Usama , I want to modify the euler code to midpoint method. I added the euler code in R. I found a code for midpoint method in Matlab so I was looking for a way to convert it to R.

Comment: The midpoint method belongs to a broader class of Runge-Kutta methods. Take a look at the `deSolve` package. The reference for `rkMethod`, as well as one of the vignettes, demonstrate how to define a function that applies the midpoint method: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/deSolve/index.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Note

<strike>Broadly speaking, I agree with the expressed comments; however, I decided to vote up this question.</strike> *(now deleted)* This is due to the existence of [**`matconv`**](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/matconv/vignettes/overallUse.html) that facilitates this process.

## Answer

Given your code, we could use [**`matconv`**](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/matconv/vignettes/overallUse.html) in the following manner:

```
pacman::p_load(matconv)
out <- mat2r(inMat = "input.m")
```

The created `out` object will attempt to translate Matlab code into R, however, the job is far from finished. If you inspect the `out` object you will see that it requires further work. Simple statements are usually translated correctly with Matlab comments `%` replaced with `#` and so forth but more complex statements may require a more detailed investigation. You could then inspect respective line and attempt to evaluate them to see where further work may be required, example:

```
eval(parse(text=out$rCode[1]))
NULL
```

*(first line is a comment so the output is NULL)*

Comment: Note that the question you answered is already asked a long time ago. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5527145/convert-matlab-code-to-r https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12246309/how-to-convert-matlab-scripts-in-r Therefore, it may be better to answer it there. However, note that such a questions are rather off-topic.

Comment: @Thanks for the comment. Is this correct? input.m=function [y t] = midpoint(f,a,b,ya,n)
h = (b - a) / n;
halfh = h / 2;
y(1,:) = ya;
t(1) = a;
for i = 1 : n
    t(i+1) = t(i) + h;
    z = y(i,:) + halfh * f(t(i),y(i,:));
    y(i+1,:) = y(i,:) + h * f(t(i)+halfh,z);
end; out <- mat2r(inMat = "input.m")

Comment: @david `input.m` is your file with Matlab code. Converted code will be available in `out$rCode[n]`, with `n` reflecting each converted line. As mentioned in my answer, more complex statements may not be translated flawlessly.